# Sharepoint 2010 DocumentLibrary WebDAV UNC path changed to http Path by OfficePrograms and no content is visible

Tags: document-library, office-integration, webdav

We have an issue with WebDAV and SharePoint2010 while trying to open files via Office2010 programs.
Example: Document Library with url: `http://servername/documents` there are no problems opening this library via WebDAV under `\\servername\davwwwroot\documents`

When i'm clicking "save as" in my Word2010 application the Dialog shows the `http://servername/documents` path but I can't see any content. Folders or files are not shown. Changing path to existing subfolder like `http://servername/documents/subfolder` works but is empty, too.

Client: Win7-64bit, IE9, Office2010 32bit

Where is the problem?

Comment: Maybe, this is because "document type" property in your dialog box is set to .docx? Are there any other .docx files in your folder you are trying to save to?

Comment: Hey Denis, thanks but it's not the problem. i have the same issue when trying to open an other document and dialog box filter is set to *.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue now.

The problem was, that I have created a documentlibrary via visualstudio 2010 based on special content type. VS2010 doesn't create full code on BaseViev 2 (FileDlg) After comparing Schema.xml of normal library with this special one, I copied the View to my schema.xml

That works